# Stack implementation in ES6

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, stack, ecmascript-6

Finally happy to see that now we can have iterators and generators. I also need to try to have private properties too so that we have well encapsulated data structures and I see that there are [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) which could help me do that.

**Utils:**

```
export const isDefAndNotNull = object =>
  object !== undefined && object !== null;

export const isIterable = object =>
  isDefAndNotNull(object) && typeof object[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
```

**Code:**

```
import {isDefAndNotNull, isIterable} from "./Utils";

function *reverseArrayGenerator(arr) {
  let i = arr.length;
  while(--i >= 0) {
    yield arr[i];
  }
}

const data = Symbol("data");

export default class {
  constructor(iterable) {
    this[data] = [];
    if (isIterable(iterable)) {
      for (let item of iterable) {
        this.push(item);
      }
    }
  }

  peek() {
    return this[data].slice(-1)[0];
  }

  push(item) {
    this[data].push(item);
  }

  pop() {
    return this[data].pop();
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this[data].length === 0;
  }

  size() {
    return this[data].length;
  }

  toString() {
    let res = [];
    for (let item of this) {
      res.push(item);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(res.join(' '));
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return reverseArrayGenerator(this[data]);
  }
}
```

**Test:**

```
import {strictEqual as equal} from "assert";
import Stack from "../src/Stack";

suite("Stack", () => {
  test("without iterator", () => {
    const s = new Stack();
    s.push(1);
    equal(s.size(), 1);
    equal(s.pop(), 1);
    equal(s.size(), 0);
  });

  test("with iterator", () => {
    let s = new Stack([1, 2, 3]);
    equal(s.size(), 3);
    s = new Stack('hello');
    equal(s.size(), 5);
    s = new Stack([{name: 'Foo'}, {name: 'Bar'}]);
    equal(s.size(), 2);
  });

  test("peek", () => {
    let s = new Stack([1, 2, 3]);
    equal(s.peek(), 3);
    s.pop();
    equal(s.peek(), 2);
  });

  test("iterator", () => {
    const s = new Stack([1, 2, 3]);
    let i = 3;
    for(let item of s) {
      equal(item, i);
      i--;
    }
  });
});
```

Reference: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Stack.java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Why are you using a symbol for the data? If you're hoping for private variables, **[you're out of luck](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/object/getownpropertysymbols)**.
- `return JSON.stringify(res.join(' '));` Why? Why not just `return JSON.stringify([...this])` or something? Why both join into a string *and* JSON stringify?
- `return this[data].slice(-1)[0];` is inefficient as it needlessly copies the array for each call. `return this[data][this.size()];` should be (if marginally) better.
- Why is your `reverseArrayGenerator` generator function not in Utils?
- `isDefAndNotNull`, while nice, can be shortened or completely dropped. Shortened to `object != null` which is exactly the same thing, or dropped altogether in favor of:   `object && typeof object[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';`

I won't repeat what the other answer says, but it's also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, JS arrays are essentially stacks (they have `push` and `pop`). So I'm not sure why you need to reimplement a stack in JS.

```
if (isIterable(iterable)) {
  for (let item of iterable) {
    this.push(item);
  }
}
```

JS has the spread operator. Additionally, `array.push` actually accepts more than one argument, pushing each item in order. This means you can do this:

```
const anotherArray = [1,2,3];

// Choose your weapon
array.push(1); array.push(2); array.push(3);
array.push(1,2,3);
Array.prototype.push.apply(array, anotherArray);
array.push(...anotherArray);
```

This assumes an array as the argument though. Other iterables might need the `for-of`.

Comment: First thing first, the concept of [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) isn't implementation language specific, they provide us a interface to speak and here I have implemented that interface, like what is the `size` of the stack? is the stack `empty`? I forgot the bound check otherwise it would shout at the user and give them `StackUnderflow` error. What about `pop` or `peek`? do you think its a good idea to re-implement it again and again for any specific problem?

Comment: Regarding `Iterable` I don't think that I would go for `spread` operator because I need to take different path for array and other iterable like `Set`.

Comment: Well, if implementing the interface is all you wanted, you could have done `class Stack extends Array` and just implement `size()`, `peek()` and `isEmpty()`.